# Usage of 'yesterday' for future

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need <something> yesterday?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/i-need-something-yesterday)

For couple of times, mostly in movies, I realized that *yesterday* is commonly used for future. Here is an example sentence:

> I want it done. I want it done yesterday!

So, what is the exact meaning of *yesterday* here? Is it used here in order to express the urgency of the situation? If so, what separates it from *right now*?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "I *wanted* it done yesterday?"

Comment: @Ham if it was 'I wanted it done yesterday?', there would be no point to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's to emphasize that something needs to be done with such urgency that actually you wanted it to have been already done -- yesterday. In other words, "I want it right now, in fact, it would have been better if you had already done it yesterday."

Comment: thanks. Also it is used in such an angry manner most of the time.